# Why is the @forward naming prefix not working with variables using Sass?

Tags: css, reactjs, sass

I am learning `Sass` over here and would like to get support in understanding why does this prefixing attribute not working when referencing `variables` when forwarding `scss` files.

I am using `dart-sass` with `react.js` taking the advantage of `package-aliasing` over `node-sass` so I can use `@use`, etc.

I cannot use this on `codesandbox` in order to replicate the issue, so I will post the code down here:

At `src/library` I have 2 partial `scss` files and one `index.scss` file to `@forward` my stuff:

**_variables.scss**

```
$color: darkgreen;
```

**_mixins.scss**

```
@mixin box-structure {
    width: 50vw;
    height: 50vw;
    background-color: yellow;
    margin: 0;
}
```

**index.scss**

```
@forward 'mixins' as mix-*;
@forward 'variables' as var-*;
```

the `index.scss` file is imported to a dummy `react` component, just to play around with the features and understand how things work.

Here is the **Child1.js** file and subsequently the **Child1.scss** file:

**Child1.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import './Child1.scss'

export default function Child1(props) {
    return (
        <div className="Child1">
            <h2>Child 1 Title</h2>
        </div>
    )
}
```

**Child1.scss**

```
@use '../library/index.scss' as i;

@function invert($color, $amount: 100%) {
    $inverse: change-color($color, $hue: hue($color) + 180);
    @return mix($inverse, $color, $amount);
  }
  
  $primary-color: #036;  

.Child1 {
    @include i.mix-box-structure; //this works as intended
    background-color: invert($primary-color);
    h2 {
        color: i.var-$color; //here is where the error occurs
}
}
```

As demonstrated above, I import `index.scss` as `i` and apply it on two places in `Child1.scss`:

When I use it to apply a `mixin` it works just fine, but when I try to apply the prefix to use a `variable` I get the following error:

```
SassError: expected "(".
   ╷
14 │         color: i.var-$color;
   │                      ^
```

I guess it is not accepting the `$` after the dash. I tried placing the `variable` using `string-interpolation` with no success. Would it be a `react.js` issue?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the Problem is the application of the forwarding prefix. you need to add it after the $ like:

```
color: i.$var-color
```

It looks weird but if i remember correctly thats how forwarding prefixes work in sass.

Comment: Wow! I did not imagine that the ```$``` symbol would jump from the ```variable``` name itself to a position coming before the file prefix in this case! I did not find this at the docs at all! I guess that whoever is familiar with ```ruby``` syntax would have figured this naturally. Thanks very much for the interesting insight!